# Typescript: How to set method return value => subclass

Tags: typescript

I have a parent class with two subclasses:

```
abstract class Point {
    public readonly x: number;
    public readonly y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    diff(point: Point): Point {
        return this.update(this.x - point.x, this.y - point.y);
    }
    // many methods like diff(); and then...

    protected abstract update(x: number, y: number): Point;
}



class ImmutablePoint extends Point {
    protected update(x: number, y: number): Point {
        return new ImmutablePoint(x, y);
    }
}



class MutablePoint extends Point {
    public x: number;
    public y: number;

    protected update(x: number, y: number): Point {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        return this;
    }
}


const pointA: ImmutablePoint = new ImmutablePoint(10, 10)
const pointB: ImmutablePoint = new ImmutablePoint(6, 2);
```

But `diff()` method returns a Point, not a ImmutablePoint

```
// Error: type 'Point' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ImmutablePoint'.
const result: ImmutablePoint = pointA.diff(pointB);
```

I'm looking for a way to re-define the method signature on the subclass without writing a new implementation, is it possible?

I also tried to make `diff()` return value `this` but it doesn't work because ImmutablePoint doesn't return `this` but a new ImmutablePoint

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20abstract%20class%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20readonly%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20readonly%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.y%20%3D%20y%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20diff(point%3A%20Point)%3A%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.update(this.x%20-%20point.x%2C%20this.y%20-%20point.y)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20many%20methods%20like%20diff()%3B%20and%20then...%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20protected%20abstract%20update(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20Point%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20ImmutablePoint%20extends%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20protected%20update(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20ImmutablePoint(x%2C%20y)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20MutablePoint%20extends%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20protected%20update(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.y%20%3D%20y%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20pointA%3A%20ImmutablePoint%20%3D%20new%20ImmutablePoint(10%2C%2010)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20pointB%3A%20ImmutablePoint%20%3D%20new%20ImmutablePoint(6%2C%202)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20type%20'Point'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'ImmutablePoint'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20result%3A%20ImmutablePoint%20%3D%20pointA.diff(pointB)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Why note just make `result` of type `Point`? Code to the "interface" instead.

Comment: Yes, in fact you can use the superclass as type instead of the subclass anywhere but the reason why we have ImmutablePoints is to be used mainly as (immutable) parameters, and a Point has to be casted every time. Quite annoying. Actually just saw the error I pasted says "parameter of type" :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have `this` as a return type and you can access the constructor of your current object with `this.constructor`. That allows you to work more easily with subclassed immutables.

```
abstract class Point {
    public readonly x: number;
    public readonly y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    diff(point: Point): this {
        return this.update(this.x - point.x, this.y - point.y);
    }
    // many methods like diff(); and then...

    protected abstract update(x: number, y: number): this;
}



class ImmutablePoint extends Point {
    protected update(x: number, y: number): this {
        return new (<any>this.constructor)(x, y);
    }
}



class MutablePoint extends Point {
    public x: number;
    public y: number;

    protected update(x: number, y: number): this {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        return this;
    }
}


const pointA: ImmutablePoint = new ImmutablePoint(10, 10)
const pointB: ImmutablePoint = new ImmutablePoint(6, 2);
const result: ImmutablePoint = pointA.diff(pointB);
```

Comment: I didn't know `this` could me a new instance

Comment: Whoops, I fixed the missing 'new'. Sorry for the lateness

Answer (score 8):

You can make `Point` generic:

```
abstract class Point<T extends Point<any>> {
    public readonly x: number;
    public readonly y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        ...
    }

    diff(point: Point<any>): T {
        return this.update(this.x - point.x, this.y - point.y);
    }

    protected abstract update(x: number, y: number): T;
}

class ImmutablePoint extends Point<ImmutablePoint> {
    protected update(x: number, y: number): ImmutablePoint {
        return new ImmutablePoint(x, y);
    }
}

class MutablePoint extends Point<MutablePoint> {
    public x: number;
    public y: number;

    protected update(x: number, y: number): MutablePoint {
        ...
        return this;
    }
}


const pointA: ImmutablePoint = new ImmutablePoint(10, 10)
const pointB: ImmutablePoint = new ImmutablePoint(6, 2);
const result: ImmutablePoint = pointA.diff(pointB); // fine
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20Point%3CT%20extends%20Point%3Cany%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20readonly%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20readonly%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.y%20%3D%20y%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20diff(point%3A%20Point%3Cany%3E)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.update(this.x%20-%20point.x%2C%20this.y%20-%20point.y)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20abstract%20update(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ImmutablePoint%20extends%20Point%3CImmutablePoint%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20update(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20ImmutablePoint%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20ImmutablePoint(x%2C%20y)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MutablePoint%20extends%20Point%3CMutablePoint%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20update(x%3A%20number%2C%20y%3A%20number)%3A%20MutablePoint%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.y%20%3D%20y%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20pointA%3A%20ImmutablePoint%20%3D%20new%20ImmutablePoint(10%2C%2010)%0D%0Aconst%20pointB%3A%20ImmutablePoint%20%3D%20new%20ImmutablePoint(6%2C%202)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20result%3A%20ImmutablePoint%20%3D%20pointA.diff(pointB)%3B))

With the new [Default generic type variables](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2175) feature available you should be able to do something like:

```
abstract class Point<T extends Point = Point> {
  ...
}
```

(haven't tested it yet)