# Proper return type for an abstract function that copies a subclass

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract class that has a public instance method copy() used for copying itself (to avoid mutating data).  The logic for actually making the copy(), however, lives in a protected abstract makeACopy() method that must be implemented by each subclass to ensure it copies itself with the correct constructor.

The problem I'm having is that I can't get typescript to infer the return type of the public copy() method to be the subclass from which it's actually called.  Let me illustrate:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    protected data: number
    constructor(data?: number) {
        this.data = data ? data : 0
    }
    protected abstract makeACopy() //???

    public copy() {
        return this.makeACopy()
    }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor(data?: number){
        super(data)
    }
    protected makeACopy(){
        const newClass = new MyClass()
        newClass.data = this.data
        return newClass
    }
}

let x = new MyClass(4)
let y = x.copy()
//  ^-- I want this to be inferred as MyClass, not BaseClass
```

I've tried typing the return type as BaseClass in the protected abstract declaration, but that obviously makes it too generic.  I've tried `protected abstract makeACopy<T extends BaseClass>():T`, but that errors (and also doesn't really make sense to me anyway).

This closest I could get is making the return type on the abstract declaration `this`, following a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705406/typescript-how-to-set-method-return-value-subclass).  But that leads to an error on the subclass declaration that "this" could be instantiated with a different subtype of MyClass, which, in fairness to TypeScript, it *could*; it's just not what I'm doing here.

I feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious here, but I can't figure out what it is.

Here's [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYVXQQG8AoBChABygHsId4cATBZ4CYALgQDsBXALYgcUcpVi1ekKP3i0oACnacA-DwHDRAShLjKlCAAsAlmAB0K4AgC8bDtdX3OCHgAZ9CAL6ea9RgysoDJwiILAANY4AIJ4tFQAnoq6APQpqhmkvvwgyCawSPFJumQGBlA4EPxQvAjGZubhUbFFyZ4%20PqQoaBgAsgkEPQg4AB4MvMwY2GD4hBilElIychAKyg7qfEIiUNoLZQhg-FSi65za7b50DEysTTFxicn7ZZLSiLw4AO6DRHafXwQ-V%20YDaBwoAJBlgctjqpgsVk85Uq1VqkLml06yEqCBGsIBQIGc0UABYLtjEAlYSNzJInhc0hQAHoAWhZCAAkggvsBeIh6hhVggRAgTLwAGaiCpBPpEnoAGj49CwuBBQA).

**Update**: I now see that it works if I defined `protected abstract makeACopy(): this` and then make the subclass method:

```
protected makeACopy(){
    const newClass = new MyClass()
    newClass.data = this.data
    return newClass as this
}
```

I don't really love the cast though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```js
abstract class BaseClass<T extends BaseClass<T>> {
  protected data: number
  constructor(data?: number) {
    this.data = data ? data : 0
  }
  protected abstract makeACopy(): T

  public copy() {
    return this.makeACopy()
  }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass<MyClass> {
  constructor(data?: number) {
    super(data)
  }
  protected makeACopy() {
    const newClass = new MyClass()
    newClass.data = this.data
    return newClass
  }
}

let x = new MyClass(4)
let y = x.copy() /// inferred type is MyClass
```

Comment: Oh, interesting.  This seems better than my cast-the-return-to-this solution in my update above, and its a nice way to have the type of a subclass available in class methods. Is there no way to avoid the redundant declaration of `class MyClass extends BaseClass<MyClass>`?

Comment: I dont think so, because `BaseClass` needs to have some indication of its supertypes to have proper typing for methods defined in BaseClass.
we had exactly same use case, which you can find here
https://github.com/tmtsoftware/esw-ts/blob/master/lib/src/models/params/ParameterSetType.ts

Not only just in typescript but almost any other lang, you ll have to do something like this, for example same is done in scala here:
https://github.com/tmtsoftware/csw/blob/master/csw-params/shared/src/main/scala/csw/params/core/generics/ParameterSetType.scala